# Find the $[\Bbb{R} ^{\text{alg}}:\Bbb{Q}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

If we have the field extension $\Bbb{R}:\Bbb{Q}$, we define the set 
$$\Bbb{R} ^{\text{alg}}:=\{a\in \Bbb{R}: a \text{ is algebraic over }\Bbb{Q}  \}$$
We want to show that $\Bbb{R}^{\text{alg}}$ is a subfield of $\Bbb{R}$ and find the $[\Bbb{R} ^{\text{alg}}:\Bbb{Q}]$.

***Answer:***

If we consider that $a,b\in \Bbb{R} ^{\text{alg}} \iff a,b$ are algebraic over $\Bbb{Q} $, we have that the extension $\Bbb{Q}(a,b):\Bbb{Q}$ is algebraic over $\Bbb{Q}$. We know that $\Bbb{Q}(a,b)$ is a field, so $a-b\in \Bbb{Q}(a,b)$ and if $b\neq 0,\ ab^{-1} \in \Bbb{Q}(a,b)$, and from the previous observation are algebraic. So, $a-b,\ ab^{-1} \in \Bbb{R}^{\text{alg}}$. And this means $\Bbb{R}^{\text{alg}} \leq\mathbb{R}$.

Right? 
And how can we find the $[\Bbb{R} ^{\text{alg}}:\Bbb{Q}]$?

*Thank you in advance.*

Comment: Do you have any guesses about what $[\Bbb R^{\rm alg}:\Bbb Q]$ might be?

Comment: @arctictern Thank you for your comment. Maybe $\infty$? But I can't find a way to determine a basis!

Comment: Who said anything about determining a basis?

Comment: Ok. What about the tower law: $[\Bbb{R}:\Bbb{Q}]=[\Bbb{R}:\Bbb{R}^{\text{alg}}][\Bbb{R}^{\text{alg}}:\Bbb{Q}]$

Comment: See this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552220/proving-that-mathbba-alpha-in-mathbbc-alpha-text-is-algebraic-ove?rq=1

Comment: We're not trying to find $[\Bbb R:\Bbb Q]$.

Comment: @Jonas Thank you for your comment. I tried to understand this link, but I can't catch it. Could you please give me a help?

Comment: Find a lower bound on the degree of the extension by finding appropriate subfields. Show that you can take this lower bound to be as large as you want.